# How to interpret $\delta(x\pm ct)$ as the solution to the wave equation?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, distribution-theory

Consider the equation:

$$\left(\Delta-\frac{1}{c^2}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2}\right)u(x,t)=0,\qquad(x,t\in\mathbb{R})\qquad(\star)$$

where $c>0$ is a constant.

Then I believe we have general solutions of the form

$$u(x,t)=\delta(x\pm ct),$$

which are plane waves.

From a more rigorous perspective, how should I interpret this? Does it mean that $(\star)$ has no regular solutions which exist as functions and therefore require us to extend to the theory of distributions? In this case, I suppose we would have to weight $\delta$ against a test function $\varphi\in\mathscr{S}(\mathbb{R})$ so that

$$u(x,t)=\langle T_{\pm ct\ast} \delta_x,\varphi\rangle=\langle\delta_x,T_{\pm ct}^\ast\varphi\rangle=\langle\delta,\varphi\circ T_{\pm ct}\rangle,$$

for all $\varphi\in\mathscr{S}(\mathbb{R})$, where $\delta_x:\mathscr{S}(\mathbb{R})\to\mathbb{C}$ which maps $\langle\delta_x,\varphi\rangle=\varphi(x)$ is the Dirac measure at $x\in\mathbb{R}$, $T_{\pm ct\ast}\in\operatorname{End}(\mathscr{S}'(\mathbb{R}))$ is the extension of the continuous linear operator $T_{\pm ct}^\ast\in\operatorname{End}(\mathscr{S}(\mathbb{R}))$, where $T_{\pm ct}:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is the translation operator which maps $x\mapsto x\pm ct$?

Of course, another way of interpreting this is to take the Fourier transform of $(\star)$ with respect to the $t$ variable, which yields

$$\left(\Delta+\frac{\omega^2}{c^2}\right)u(x,t)=0,$$

so that

$$u(x,\omega)=e^{\pm i\omega x/c},$$

which is well defined as a function.

I suppose that I am basically asking how one interprets plane waves in a mathematically rigorous manner?

Answer (score 2):

We need not invoke generalized functions here.  Note that the general solution to the wave equation

$$\left(\Delta -\frac1{c^2}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2}\right)u(x,t)=0 \tag1$$

is given by

$$u(x,t)=f(x-ct)+g(x+ct)$$

> **for any arbitrary pair of twice differentiable functions $f$ and $g$.**

---

Upon taking the Fourier Transform of $(1)$, we obtain

$$\left(\Delta +\frac{\omega^2}{c^2}\right)U(x,\omega)=0 \tag2$$

which has general plane wave solutions

$$U(x,\omega)=\frac1cF(-\omega)e^{-i\omega x/c}+\frac1cG(\omega)e^{i\omega x/c}$$

---

Comment: Thanks for the answer! One of the signs in your expression for $u(x,t)=f(x+ct)+g(x-ct)$ is incorrect though and in equation (2) you should have a $+$ sign instead of a $-$ sign as the Fourier transform of the double derivative yields an $i^2=-1$.

Comment: You're welcome.  And yes, there were two typographical (sign) errors which have been corrected.

Comment: Jason, feel free to up vote and accept an answer as you see fit of course.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than being the general solution, this is something more like a fundamental solution - $G(x,t) = \frac12\left(\delta(x+ct) + \delta(x-ct)\right)$ is the (generalized) solution corresponding to the initial data $G(x,0) = \delta(x), G_t(x,0) = 0$. You should be able to check that this is true if you interpret the PDE in terms of distributional derivatives.

This means we can write the *general* solution for initial data $u(x,0) = u_0(x), u_t(x,0) = 0$ as $$u(x,t) = \int G(y,t) u_0(y) dy = \frac12\left(u_0(ct) + u_0(-ct)\right).$$

If you want to allow non-zero initial velocity then you can generalise this to the full [d'Alembert formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%27Alembert%27s_formula). Note that this gives a smooth solution $u$ for any smooth initial data $u_0$, so we certainly don't *need* to talk about distributional solutions in the sense you suggested.